# Capture raw Skype call as video source & pipe to Wirecast or VidBlaster

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, skype, podcast

I'm working on building an elaborate telecasting system where the goal is to record separate video and audio files for each participant in a Skype conference. Basically, Leo Laporte's Skypeasaurus, but with video. I'm looking at different setup configurations, and ideally, would like to avoid using separate VM instances to pipe as video sources into Wirecast (as some people propose).

I'm trying to find a way to do this by only using multiple instance of Skype running on one OS. All the proposed solutions I've seen get the Skype video by capturing the window (with Desktop Presenter) or a cropped region of the screen. This seems like such a low tech way of doing this. In addition, none of the tutorials I've seen tackle the question of more than one remote participant.

The logical solution is to capture the video straight from Skype, however this isn't offered out of the box.

**If Skype call recording software can grab the raw stream at the source and save it to a file, wouldn't there be a way to pipe that audio/video through a virtual video source to Wirecast or VidBlaster?**